# When to use {:noreply, socket} vs {:reply, :ok, socket} in a Phoenix Channel?

Tags: phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

I'm building a Javascript client app that has live communication with a Phoenix server, and wants to know if a message pushed to the server has been received. It looks like Phoenix's socket.js wants me to use something like:

```js
channel.push("mymessage", {data: 123})
  .receive("ok", function(){ console.log("Message pushed successfully"); });
```

However, I can't get this event handler to fire unless I change my return value on the Phoenix app to be `{:reply, :ok, socket}`, like so:

```elixir
  def handle_in("mymessage", %{"data" => data} = payload, socket) do
    {:reply, :ok, socket}
    # not {:noreply, socket}
  end
```

I guess it makes sense that `{:noreply, socket}` doesn't actually send a message in response to the client, but in what case would you want to send a message to the server and not have it let you know that it worked? Or am I misunderstanding something? I feel like with normal HTTP requests, you *always* check if the request was successful from the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right: `{:reply, :ok, socket}` will send a [reply message](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html#module-replies) with `"ok"`, and `{:noreply, socket}` won't send anything in response. You should use the former if you want to ensure that the message was sent, but often that's impractical or unnecessary (think of broadcasting a chat message to thousands of connected users--it's impractical to track "ack" messages for all of them).

> I feel like with normal HTTP requests, you always check if the request was successful from the client.

WebSockets exist for situations that normal HTTP requests don't work well, and one-way communication is one of those cases.

Comment: But in that example, the ack would be only to the person who sends the chat (which would be useful), not to the recipients of the broadcast.

Comment: Sure, in your example it would be fine. I'm just saying that in general, one-way communication is common with WebSockets (hence the "noreply" option).